# What action a role must have permission for to access metrics

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

in our subscription we have some Notification Hubs. And we have a customized role to enable Key Users to manage only these Notification Hubs. But these users are currently not able to see any of the monitoring data about the hubs. When they open the monitoring tab the diagram is just empty.

So I am wondering what action do I need to give them permission to, in order to enable them to manage and see the monitoring data about their notfication hubs.

The current permissions look like this:
[image]

thx, Kristof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring charts, autoscale settings and alerts are part of the **Microsoft.Insights** namespace. See this article for more information: 
[Monitoring permissions and custom RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-roles-permissions-security#monitoring-permissions-and-custom-rbac-roles)

So you need to give the users the following permissions:

- **Microsoft.Insights/MetricDefinitions/Read** - Read metric definitions (list of available metric types for a resource).
- **Microsoft.Insights/Metrics/Read** - Read metrics for a resource.