# What permission will allow me to view Azure Monitor Alerts?

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

I have an Azure App Service enviroment that occasionally encounters performance degradation alerts, but when I click the "See in Azure Portal" button on the notification email, I land up with a blank screen:
[image]

The URL looks similar to:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AlertDetailsTemplateBlade/alertId/XXX%2fMicrosoft.AlertsManagement%2falerts%2fXXX/invokedFrom/emailnoncommonschema

I must not have the right permission/access setup to view this - could anyone advise on how to rectify this?

Edit 1:

There's an error in the console mentioning the following permission, but I have now been assigned Monitoring Reader and Log Analytics Reader roles on the relevant App Service and App Insights for the resource in question, which grant me this permission - is there somewhere else I need to have these roles assigned?

> Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/history/read

[image]

I've also reached out on the Microsoft Q&A site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/662647/what-permissions-are-required-to-view-the-azure-pe.html)

Comment: You can refer to [Monitoring permissions and Azure custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/roles-permissions-security#monitoring-permissions-and-azure-custom-roles)

Comment: `Microsoft.Insights/LogDefinitions/Read`  and `Microsoft.Insights/eventtypes/digestevents/Read` - This permission is necessary for users who need access to the Activity Log via the portal.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @DeepDave-MT - will give some feedback once it's been assigned to my user ✌

Comment: @DeepDave-MT - the account owner set my role as a Log Analytics Reader (which I think should have worked?) but it unfortunately still displays as a blank screen... I also tried logging out and in again once my role was changed. Any other ideas?

Comment: This might be helpful:   [Where to add Monitoring Reader role in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139267/where-to-add-monitoring-reader-role-in-azure), [Manage access to log data and workspaces in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/manage-access) and [What action a role must have permission for to access metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318905/what-action-a-role-must-have-permission-for-to-access-metrics)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT - reached out on the Q&A site too, added some more details to my post here with an error I saw in the console, and the roles I've been assigned

Comment: @jarodsmk, Please assign `Monitoring Contributor` role on **resource group scope where the resources are present** or on **Subscription scope** to your **user** and let me know if that resolves the issue